# Can $p_n\#<p_{n+1}^{p_{n+1}}$ be extended to $c_n<p_{n+1}^{p_{n+1}}$ for colossally abundant $c_n$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, factorial, upper-lower-bounds

Trivially, we have $n!\le n^n$. So, for prime $p$, we have $p!\le p^p$. From here it is easy to see that for the $n$th primorial and the $(n+1)$th prime,

$p_n\#<p_{n+1}^{p_{n+1}}$

My question is:  Can this result be extended to $n$th colossally abundant number, $c_n$, such that

$c_n<p_{n+1}^{p_{n+1}}$

??

Comment: What is a colossally abundant number?

Comment: From Wikipedia, "A number $n$ is said to be colossally abundant if there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $k > 1$,

   $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}\geq\frac{\sigma(k)}{k^{1+\varepsilon}}$

where $\sigma$ denotes the sum-of-divisors function"